# Why is the drag force multiplied by the inverse normalised velocity vector?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

In pure physics texbooks, I'm seeing this formula to calculate fluid drag force:

[image]

It is clearly stated that it should be opposite to the velocity. Now to me that means, in pseudocode:

```
fd = get_drag(v) // using the above formula
if v < 0: fd = -fd
```

That is, if the velocity is negative the drag should be positive, so we invert the returned value.

However, in game code, game physics books and tutorials, I see people doing:

```
drag = -v
drag.normalise()
fd = get_drag(v)
fd *= drag
```

That is, we multiply the drag force by the (inverted) velocity unit vector.

This to me is logic in regard to the sign, but also **it scales down the drag force by a factor between 0 and 1**.

Which one is correct, and why?

PS: to be noted, normalisation involves square root, multiplications and divisions, so it's more expensive than a conditional check and subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both ideas are actually correct**, but the second code snippet seems wrong to me.

If it is the same `get_drag()` in both cases, then it should operate on a scalar, and return a negative number. It should be something like:

```
drag = v                 # No sign inversion here; get_drag() does it
drag.normalise()
fd = get_drag(length(v)) # Operate on a scalar
drag *= fd               # Get a vector
```

The first formula operates in one dimension, where the “opposite” of the velocity just means choosing a number that has the opposite sign (hence `-fd`).

The second formula operates in two or three dimensions, where a force “opposite” of the velocity has to be a scalar multiplied by a unit vector that goes in the opposite direction (hence drag.normalize()`).

Your final assumption that the drag force is “scaled down” is erroneous: a normalised vector has size 1, so the drag force is not changed. Getting the length of `drag` will give you the original drag force `fd`.

Comment: You are quite right: I had failed to notice the guy stored the speed (magnitude) separately from the velocity vector. In his code, the "get_drag" does actually work with the magnitude, so multiplying back by the normalised velocity makes sense. In my code, it works on vectors (the if case is repeated for every dimension).

I still think that my solution (I currently use abs(v)*v inside get_drag instead of v^2, so I don't have to do three if cases) it's faster than normalisation. I wonder if I'm missing something.

Anyway, thanks a lot! It was bugging me for no reason apparently :)

Comment: But you can’t do it component-wise; this is only valid for linear operations, and the `v²` in the drag formula makes it non-linear. Just compare the results you get with `v` = `[1 0 0]` and with `[0.8 0.6 0]`. Both these vector have unit length, but your method will give you 30% less drag with the second vector.